# Looking for Minecraft 1.4.6 server mod to nerf creeper explosions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm running a private Feed-the-Beast MindCrack server for Minecraft 1.4.6.

I'm about to open the server to a friend who is inexperienced with Minecraft and I'm concerned about creeper damage.

**Is there a server-side mod compatible with with Minecraft 1.4.6 & the MindCrack modpack which is able to nerf creeper explosions such that they do not break blocks?**

Bukkit is not an option as it is not compatible with this modpack.

Comment: Gravity guns are excellent for preventing creeper damage :D

Comment: @SaintWacko I don't think Gravity guns are part of the MindCrack pack.

Comment: Oh, wups. I'm used to Direwolf.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Minecraft 1.4.6 you can set the `mobGriefing` game rule to `false` to prevent creeper damage. I can't think why this wouldn't work in FTB.

Set it by typing:

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I was not aware of this feature.

Comment: darn it, you beat me to it.

Comment: @legacy [Faster than lazers](http://stackapps.com/questions/587/new-q-google-chrome-extension-notifies-you-of-new-questions-of-interest-and-i)

Comment: @Mikuso don't forget to check the ACCEPT on the left!

Comment: @Mikuso note that this will also prevent endermen from moving blocks

Comment: Good. When I see this question the first thing I think of is the mobGriefing rule.

Comment: @Mikuso It will also prevent Ghast fireball damage, and mobs trampling crops.